# How do I insert a specific character along all lines on a specific column in Vim?

Tags: vim

```
 Dates
=======

 Name                                   | Date
-------------------------------------------------
* Battle of the Plains of Abraham       | September 13, 1759
* Proclamation Act                      | October   07, 1763
* Stamp Act                             | March     22, 1765
* Guy Carleton becomes Governor         | April     07, 1766
* Boston Tea Party                      | December  16, 1773
* Quebec Act                            |
* Declaration of Independance           | <====== # How do I insert this bar character
* Treaty of Paris                                 # along the whole column?
* Constitutional Act                
* French Revolution                 
* War of 1812
```

I want to be able to insert that bar character without having to manually go and insert it. 
While this is not syntactically correct, this is supposed to be markdown.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm only a beginner, but here's what I do:

- `C-v` to enter `Visual Block` (Use `C-q` on windows)
- Select column (motion keys `hjkl`)
- `I`
- Enter text
- `Esc`

Comment: For this task, I would probably use `r|` instead of `I|<esc>`. It *replaces* each character under the cursor with the next typed character.I'd also recommend setting [`virtualedit`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'virtualedit') to `block` (`:set ve=block`), which allows you to make a columnar selection so that extends after the end-of-line character.

Comment: @nelstrom Cool, post it as an answer. I was thinking of the general case when one needs to enter more than one character (and not replace existing stuff).

Comment: Great answer! I was actually thinking of doing almost the same thing, but there was one problem. Since Visual mode needs *something* to select and there were no blank spaces or anything after the Name, the column wouldn't be selected. I'm not sure if I'm making sense there. 

**Ninjaedit**

The answer by @DigitalRoss below is *exactly* what I was looking for. It appends spaces/blanks to each line which solves the problem, though it's a tad lengthy :)

Comment: @saif - see my earlier comment about virtualedit. That solves the problem of visual block mode having to select something.

Comment: Just to clarify if it helps anyone: that's "Control-Shift-v", then select the column (can be arrow keys, too), then "Shift-i".

Answer (score 4):

```
%s/$/                                        /
v/|/s/^\(........................................\)/\1|/
%s/  *$//
```

Some notes:

- You will need a `:` in front of each line if you are in vi's normal visual mode
- Alternatively, you can put those commands in a command file and type `$ ex file < cmds` but in that case add an `x` as the fourth line
- This works by appending blanks to each line, then changing the right one to a | for lines that don't already have a |, and then deleting any trailing blanks