# Insert a character at a particular column in a given range of lines without using visual mode

Tags: vim

I have a comment block like this

```
###################
# 20a#
# I need this     #
# I all lines
# The endin #
###################
```

I would like to have like this:

```
###################
# 20a#            #
# I need this     #
# I all lines     #
# The ending #    # 
###################
```

I can do this in visual mode (enable virtual edit, select the column, r#) as also described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6090556/1610910).

However, i am looking for solution something like this, if there exists one natively:

```
:100,200r20,#
```

(With the hypothetical meaning that: replace the 20th-column character, even if past the end of line, for lines 100 to 200, with #. More general, replacing multiple characters would be even better)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can set `&ve` to `all` to do it with `:normal!`

```
:let x=&ve
:set ve=all|2,5norm! 19|r#
:let &ve=x
```

you can wrap those in a function too, if you like.

about `ve` option: `:h 've'`

P.s.

not exactly is the solution to your question, but you may want to check this out:

https://github.com/sk1418/blockit

Answer (score 1):

If you're really determined to do it this way, you can:

```viml
:100,200g!/\m^.\{20}/s/$/\=repeat(' ', 20-strdisplaywidth(getline('.')))/
:100,200s/\m^.\{19}\zs./#/
```

The point of the first command is to fill up the lines up to the required length.  The point of the second line is to add the `#` characters.

You can also turn the above into a command:

```viml
function! FillHash(line1, line2)              
    let max_len = max(map(getline(a:line1, a:line2), 'strdisplaywidth(v:val)')) + 1
    for n in range(a:line1, a:line2)
        let line = getline(n)
        call setline(n, line . repeat(' ', max_len - strdisplaywidth(line)) . '#')
    endfor
endfunction
command! -range FillHash call FillHash(expand(<line1>), expand(<line2>))
```

You'd then call the command like this:

```viml
:100,200FillHash
```

However, I'd suggest you to use [Par](http://www.nicemice.net/par/) instead.